# How can I open a folder in explorer.exe with a comma in the folder name?

Tags: batch-file

I have made a shortcut for opening folders based on job numbers for work. It looks through the job directory for the job number and then opens that folder. Unfortunately, this fails when the folder name has a comma "," in it:

```
IF %JOBNUM%==!JOBTEST! %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %%G
```

Where, for example:

```
%%G = X:\A12300-12399\A123456 - Job with, comma
```

Instead of opening the job folder, it just opens My Documents (which, I assume, is the default location for Explorer.

Is there a way to let it know that the comma is part of the folder name and not some sort of delimiter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the path inside quotes like "***path***"

Batch files are essentially shell commands executed as a batch. Commands are delimited by space, "," , "=" etc. As shown [Here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
When you use a pathname with a delimiter, windows takes the first string to be the actual value and discards the rest. Using quotes is explicitly instructing the shell to treat everything inside the quotes as a single unit. That goes the same for %%G.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. But, can you explain why that doesn't just make it try to open "%%G" in explorer? How do double quotes operate in Batch files?

Comment: Edited answer to include explanation @MowgliB